# What To Do When a Guard Fails

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling, type-safety

My question basically is, what are some normal things to do when a guard fails? I am mostly asking in the context of an iOS application, where user interaction has requested something to happen and something must now be performed. Due to Swifts type-safety (which I love) we now may have optional values to take care of.

Here is an example:

```
guard let textField = (tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 1)) as? TextInputTableViewCell)?.inputField else {
     print("Couldn't get the keyboard when a user clicked on done, method: accesoryKeyboardDone")
     return
}
```

Usually, I either log the failure and return or if it's vital that value is present, I'll `fatalError` out of the method. This seems like the wrong way to do this? Is there some way to fall back to a better case and still perform what the user has asked for? I like safely unwrapping values even though I need them to be there as force unwrapping makes me feel dirty and like I'm not doing something correctly. Is this something that I should be doing or is force unwrapping acceptable for these cases?

What are some ways that you approach handling optional values? I'm really just looking for opinions and tips on how other handle it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user should only be alerted for things that you expect to fail; for instance a network request that doesn't go through because they don't have internet.  You don't have to alert the user for every single possible error; its often sufficient to either log it or just exit scope.  Also you don't always need to pop up an alert box. See [DZNEmptySet](https://github.com/dzenbot/DZNEmptyDataSet) as an example.

Comment: So for example, a deletion of an object from a database goes wrong. Would it be appropriate to alert the user then? If not what should be done, user is expecting some sort of feedback

Answer (score 1):

Show an error message in a [`UIAlertController`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uialertcontroller).

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Default Style", message: "A standard alert.", preferredStyle: .Alert)

let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel) { action in
    // ...
}
alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { action in
    // ...
}
alertController.addAction(OKAction)

self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true) {
    // ...
}
```

Example code is from [NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/uialertcontroller/).

Comment: Hmm, I thought of this, is this acceptable UI practice though? Alerts get annoying, but I guess if there's no way to fall back, then this seems like the only possible thing to do besides crashing the app which is a bad idea.

Comment: @Luis crashing the app isn't always a bad idea.

Comment: @Alexander when would you say it's not a bad idea to crash the app?

Comment: @Luis When you have an unforeseen, fundamentally unrecoverable error that gives you no other option. Doing anything but crashing risks compromising user data. (e.g. some integrity check fails, but you decide to ignore and it and overwrite a file, replacing its previously valid contents with new garbage)

Comment: @Luis That's the whole reason why force unwrapping `nil` causes a crash. It's not a fluke, it was **intentionally designed** to crash, for exactly this reason.

Comment: @Alexander I understand that logic, wouldn't want to write bad data, however as a user would you personally expect a crash or some sort of dialog telling you what went wrong?

Comment: @Luis If that can be done safely, sure. What if this happens if you get an out-of-memory error, and can't allocate the UI objects necessary to present such a dialog?

Comment: @Alexander that's a valid argument, there's definitely different scenarios like you bring up. I'm still fairly new to developing application so thanks for the info!